# C++ Include Problem in Event Listener Pattern

Tags: c++, oop, include, header-files, event-listener

I am trying to use EventListener Pattern (instead of Observer) in my project. Basically:

1. `Entity`s can register themselves as listeners for certain  types of `Event`s
2. `Entity`s can report an `Event` to `EventListener`.
3. When an `Event` is being reported, `EventListener` will notify `Entity` instances that are registered to receive this type of `Event`.

The two classes are:

```
class Entity:
void Register(std::string type); // calls EventListener::RegisterListener(this, type);
void ReportEvent(Event event); // calls EventListener::BroadcastEvent(event);
void OnNotify(Event event); // called by EventListener::BroadcastEvent(event);

class EventListener:
void RegisterListener(Entity* listener, Event event);
void BroadcastEvent(Event event); // calls Entity::OnNotify(event) for all relative Entity instances
```

Notice that in `Entity::ReportEvent()` calls `EventListener::RegisterListener()`, and `EventListener::BroadcaseEvent()` calls `Entity::OnNotify()`. Doing a simple forward declaration cannot enable this dual-linked calling. What should I do? Can I directly `#include` each other in their `.hpp` files (Which I highly doubt)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is way easier than I thought. You can directly `#include` the header files with each other. Just remember to add the header guards (`#ifndef ENTITY_HPP #define ENTITY_HPP #endif`).